# Getting error 404 when use basic auth

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, authorization, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a GET query using Fetch but I'm getting an error 404 when passing the Authorization.
I don't know why this error happens because the server responds well when I use a tool like Postman.

```
Authorization: Basic ...
method: GET
url: https://zammad.zonngo.com/api/v1/ticket_articles
```

When I use `Javascript fetch API` the error 404 appears.

```
OPTIONS https://zammad.zonngo.com/api/v1/ticket_articles 404 (Not Found)
```

There's my code:

```
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Authorization','Basic ...');
myHeaders.append('Content-Type','application/json');
fetch(URLTICKETS, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
.then(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Would be nice if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GET` method on the URL returns a 401 status code **but** the `OPTIONS` method actually returns a 404.

```
 http OPTIONS https://zammad.zonngo.com/api/v1/ticket_articles
 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Encoding: gzip
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 01:37:59 GMT
 Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 X-Request-Id: 16f58319-2658-4b0e-824c-08ca68e8d401
 X-Runtime: 0.003135
```

The `OPTIONS` is probably caused by a CORS preflight request which does not seem to be handled correctly by `https://zammad.zonngo.com/`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request